# What is more expensive? Creating a new ArrayAdapter every time the data changes or updating an existing ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

To update a Listview we can do following two things:

1) Create a new ArrayAdapter and bind it to ListView everytime the data is updated.

```
this.listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), data));
```

or

2) Update the contents of ArrayAdapter which is already binded to listview:

```
this.arrayadapter.clear();
for (Data item : data)
    this.arrayadapter.add(item);
this.arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So which method is more expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it, the second one is definitely more expensive. `ArrayAdapter` calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` internally in `clear()` as well as in `add()`. You could change it to

```
this.arrayadapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
this.arrayadapter.clear();
for (Data item : data)
    this.arrayadapter.add(item);
this.arrayadapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
this.arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But even if you it this way, both calls contain a synchronized block which makes them slow. So even though you are creating a new `ArrayAdapter` in the first method, I would say it is faster.

You could further optimize it by using a custom adapter with a `setItems(data)` method that just replaces the internal data list.

Comment: According to the document, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` resets the `NotifyOnChange` flag to true, so that line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd becareful with the accepted answers final conclusion. While SimonSays makes valid points about the iteration and adding...there's a lot that happens with setting a new adapter he fails to recognize.  Which makes it hard to say if it's actually any better then the suggested for...each approach.

Setting a new adapter will cause the ListView to flush out all it's recycled view's. It'll also have to re-measure all the new views coming in...which leads to the getView() being called 3-4 times per item for several of the positions...if not all positions.  (Varies with platform).  So even though there's a sync block on adding, you'll probably see the getView method invoked far less times with possibility of using recycled views.

Basically, knowing which is better is hard and depends greatly on use case. I'd vote to stick with the for...each approach simply for better readability.

Comment: I agree with you. When you have a custom adapter with a "heavy" item (multiple Views inside your custom item), redrawing them (resetting the getView recycler) and creating a new Adapter-instance, is even worse for performance than the for-loop (less noticeable with a default ArrayAdapter though). I'd say use `this.arrayadapter.addAll(dataList);` instead of the for-loop. The array adapter will most likely use a for-loop behind the scenes (I assume), but maybe it's better optimized and it also only calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` twice (`clear` and `addAll`), instead of for every `add`.